# Timers and animation

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem with animating missile move in my windows forms application. I'd like the missile to move every 0,5 second by five. Everytime I run my application I can't see it because I use space to shoot the missile then I don't see any animation, just missile appearing at the bottom of the window. I tried threading and with `thread.Sleep(1)` it works fine but I heard that timers are better for it.

**My code looks like that:**

```
this.Controls.Add(missile);
System.Timers.Timer t1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
t1.Interval = 500;
t1.Start();
while (missile.Location.Y > 0)
{
    missile.Location = new Point(missile.Location.X, missile.Location.Y - 5);
}
t1.Stop();
```

Comment: I don't believe that WinForm is a good candidate for creating games. If you really want to create games, use a good game framework.

Comment: @Steve B: WinForms is fine for creating simple games. Certainly a reasonable way to start if you're just learning.

Comment: Isn't XNA simple enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the code inside `Timer` class's `Elapsed` event like:

```
this.Controls.Add(missile);
System.Timers.Timer t1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
t1.Interval = 500;
t1.Elapsed += (sender, args) => 
{
  if (missile.Location.Y > 0)
  {
    missile.Location = new Point(missile.Location.X, missile.Location.Y - 5);
  }
};
t1.Start();
```

Comment: @MarcinZalas: then you can also mark it as the accepted answer so the question doesn't show up anymore in the questions list.